# Why does adding more external functions adds more cost to a smart contract?

Tags: contract-design, gas-limit

Please let me know to delete the question if it's already been asked.

---

I was told (by a colleague of mine) that adding more external function to a smart contract increases its gas. I tested (on remix and metamask) and it's true, for example when my contract has only one external function and one internal function the total gas is: 89941.
But if I change the internal one to external function, (so two external functions) then the gas would be 99943.

**Question**: Why does a contract having more external function require more gas (when it's deployed)? Is it due to memory/storage allocation?

Comment: Is this about deploying the contract?

Comment: @cleanunicorn yes that's right. I've edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For each public or external function the contract has to have code that accept a calls to the function. For internal or private function no code is generated (you cannot call to them from other contracts).

If you use external in a function it will force the function to always use a external call when you use the function (ie `CALL` opcode). Usually the solidity compiler will make function calls to be jumps (ie `JMP` opcode).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Am I right that, because for an external function some extra code is required and this occupies some storage, the external functions impose some costs on the contract?

Comment: Yes, an external and public functions requires some extra code for the contract to accepts calls to them.